# Regex how to get 3 groups of lines out of multiple lines

Tags: regex-group

Looking to get 3 groups of lines out of multiple lines with Regex
The first and last group are a know amount of lines. The amount may differ from list to list, but is always known.
The group in the middle is whatever amount of lines are left in between.
Text will always have at least, the amount of lines of the top + the bottom group, so no need to check if there are enough lines

I got as far as what is shown in the code below, applied to the following example text:

```
This could
be "words"
or any text
or pattern
or any amount of lines
need 3 groups:
1 -> lines 1 to 2
2 -> lines leftover
3 -> last 3 lines
```

To achieve this I got this far:

```
^((.*\n){1,2})(.*)((.*\n){0,2}.*\n?\z)
```

But it is not giving the desired results

The expected results is:

Group 1 is line 1 and 2
Group 3 is the last 3 lines
Group 2 is the lines left in between

The actual results can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/DwE9QR/4)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should remove "m" flag and set "s". It will allow you to treat whole text as single line (not as multi-line text where regexp is applied to each line).

Second, learn "ungreedy" modifiers. Expression `.*\n` will match whole text because `*` is greedy, `.*?\n` will match one line because `*?` is ungreedy.

Third, this online validator is wrong, specifically its support of numeric quantifiers is broken. For example, `^(.+?[\n]+){1}(.*?)$` correctly matches first line and the rest. However, if I change to `{2}` then it matches 2nd line instead of first two lines.

Though, you can re-write without using numeric quantifiers :)

```
^([^\n]+?[\n][^\n]+?[\n])((?:[^\n]+?\n)*?)([^\n]+?[\n][^\n]+?[\n][^\n]+?[\n]*)$
```

Link https://regex101.com/r/orjKVI/2

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderPavlov
I wanted to combine the groups in this format: 1st item of $1\t 1st item of group $2
`This could need 3groups:`
`be "words" 1 -> lines 1 to 2`
and so on...

To illustrate, I created [another version](https://regex101.com/r/orjKVI/4) and [here too](https://regexr.com/4dl9o)
I changed it to the m flag, thinking it will do the trick, but it did not.

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: "m" flag splits text into lines and applies your regexp line by line so it will not help you. So you want combine 1st lines from 1st and 3rd groups?

Comment: So, I am looking  to combine `$2\t$3\t$1` for all lines in each group. So the first line after  the substitution from [this example](https://regex101.com/r/orjKVI/2) would be  `or any text\t1 -> lines 1 to 2\tThis could`, `or pattern\t2 -> lines leftover\tbe "words"`, `or any amount of lines\t3 -> last 3 lines\t` and so on

Comment: I do not think you can combine this way using substitutions. You can split into groups using regexp and do post-processing. However, it appears whole thing is easier to solve without regexp because all you need is split into the lines. What language do you use?

Comment: That is what I thought, that is would not be possible to do everything in regexp. I will do post processing in my language after splitting. Thanks for your help